# Lock/Unlock One Cell Based on Value of Another Cell VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have done a decent amount of reading about this on this site and a couple others and have not found a solution that works quite yet.

I have a simple calculator built for work in which we need to lock D7 if a Numerical Value other than 0 is entered in D6, unlock if value is zero. Then also lock D6 if a Value other than 0 is entered in D7, unlock if value is zero. It's sort of circular...however I do not want someone able to enter a value in one cell if there is a value in the other.

Also, all the cells in the worksheet are always locked except D4, D5, D6, and D7. D4 & D5 will always be unlocked.

Below is my current shot at making this work.

*CODE*

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Range("D6").Value <> 0 Then
ActiveSheet.Unprotect ""
        Range("D7").Locked = True
    ElseIf Range("D6").Value = 0 Then
        Range("D7").Locked = False
ActiveSheet.Protect ""
    End If

    If Range("D7").Value <> 0 Then
ActiveSheet.Unprotect ""
        Range("D6").Locked = True
    ElseIf Range("D7").Value = 0 Then
        Range("D6").Locked = False
ActiveSheet.Protect ""
    End If
End Sub
```

*CODE*

Problem is I am getting an error on entering 0 in D6 after having a value, and then just getting an error in general when I enter a value in D7 when D6 is 0.

Unable to set the Locked property of the Range class.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you want this

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    ActiveSheet.Unprotect ""
    If Range("D6").Value <> 0 Then
        Range("D7").Locked = True
    ElseIf Range("D6").Value = 0 Then
        Range("D7").Locked = False
    End If

    If Range("D7").Value <> 0 Then
        Range("D6").Locked = True
    ElseIf Range("D7").Value = 0 Then
        Range("D6").Locked = False
    End If
    ActiveSheet.Protect ""
End Sub
```

Comment: That worked perfectly, thank you! Looks like I had the ActiveSheet.Protect too many times and in the wrong places.

Comment: Dear Colin, If the answer is Ok, you need to mark it. You will find a Tick Mark beside the answer, just click on that.